# Problem with expandable child component in parent v-data-table using Vuetify 2

Tags: vuetify.js

I upgraded to Vuetify 2 from 1.5. Everything went pretty smoothly except for one thing. I have a parent component with a v-data-table and I want to pass data and expand each row with a child component.

ScanGrid(parent component):

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-card>
      <v-card-text>
        <v-layout row align-center>
          <v-data-table
            :headers="headers"
            :items="items"
            :hide-default-footer="true"
            item-key="id"
          >
            <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
              <tr @click="props.expanded = !props.expanded">
                <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
                <td class="text-xs-left large-column">
                  {{ props.item.scanned }}
                </td>
                <td class="text-xs-left large-column">
                  {{ props.item.incoming }}
                </td>
                <td class="text-xs-left large-column">
                  {{ props.item.outgoing }}
                </td>
                <td class="text-xs-left large-column">
                  {{ props.item.unknown }}
                </td>
              </tr>
            </template>
            <template slot="expand" slot-scope="props">
              <ScanGridChild :value="props.item"></ScanGridChild>
            </template>
          </v-data-table>
        </v-layout>
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

ScanGridChild(child component):

```
<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-card-text>{{ value }}</v-card-text>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "ScanGridChildComponent",
  props: {
    value: {
      Type: Object,
      Required: true
    }
  },
  computed: {},
  watch: {
    props: function(newVal, oldVal) {
      console.log("Prop changed: ", newVal, " | was: ", oldVal);
      this.render();
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

It worked fine in Vuetify 1.5.19. I'm on Vuetify 2.1.6 and using single file components. Thanks.

Comment: Which version of vue exactly you are using..?

Comment: I'm using vue 2.6.10

Comment: The below code will work fine, Let me know, if this resolves your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vuetify 2.x has major changes to many components, slot-scopes are replaced with v-slot, and many new properties and slots added to vuetify data table

Here is the working codepen reproduced the same feature with above code

https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/BaaWbKR?editors=1010

> You need to make sure that you have vue js 2.x and vuetify 2.x
>
> Parent component code:

```
<template>
      <v-container>
        <v-card>
          <v-card-text>
            <v-layout row align-center>
              <v-data-table
                 :headers="headers"
                 :items="items"
                 item-key="name"
                 single-expand
                 :expanded="expanded"
                 hide-default-footer
                 @click:row="clickedRow"
               >
               <template v-slot:expanded-item="{ item }">
                 <td :colspan="headers.length">
                    <ScanGridChild :value="item"></ScanGridChild>
                 </td>
               </template>
             </v-data-table>
           </v-layout>
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-container>
    </template>


    <script>
    export default {
    ...
    data () {
        return {
        expanded: [],
        headers: [
          {
            text: "Localisation",
            sortable: true,
            value: "name"
          },
          {
            text: "Paquets scannés",
            sortable: true,
            value: "scanned"
          },
          {
            text: "Paquets entrants",
            sortable: true,
            value: "incoming"
          },
          {
            text: "Paquets sortants",
            sortable: true,
            value: "outgoing"
          },
          {
            text: "Paquets inconnus",
            sortable: true,
            value: "unknown"
          }
        ],
          items: [
          {
            id: 1,
            name: "Location 1",
            scanned: 159,
            incoming: 6,
            outgoing: 24,
            unknown: 4,
            test: "Test 1"
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            name: "Location 2",
            scanned: 45,
            incoming: 6,
            outgoing: 24,
            unknown: 4,
            test: "Test 2"
          }
        ],
        }
      },
      methods: {
        clickedRow(value) {
  if (this.expanded.length && this.expanded[0].id == value.id) {
    this.expanded = [];
  } else {
    this.expanded = [];
    this.expanded.push(value);
  }
}
      }
    ...
    }
    </script>
```

> In child component

**Replace**

```
props: {
    value: {
      Type: Object,
      Required: true
    }
  },
```

> with( Type and Required change to lower case type and required)

```
props: {
    value: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },
```

Comment: I can make the previous expand close when I click another one but I can't close one when I click on it.

Comment: You have to include this.expanded = []; inside clickedRows function

Comment: Already have it. I added show-expand in v-data-table so at least there's a button to close it but it doesn't work on the whole row.

Comment: Try to implement the above code given in answer, it works as per your requirement

Comment: I did. That's really the only thing that's not working. Can't close the expand in the CodePen either.

Comment: Can you please share your code or create a codepen, that would really help to solve your issue

Comment: I might not be clear. In your CodePen if you click on the first row "Location 1" the expand opens, but when you click again on the  first row "Location 1" to close the expanded panel it doesn't close.

Comment: I have updated the codepen https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/BaaWbKR?editors=1010

Comment: Much appreciated.